# Why does Google Analytics takes forever to load

Tags: google-analytics

Since a few months I've noticed that Google Analytics takes forever to load. When inspecting the requests for a page, analytics is at the bottom as it's at the bottom of the page but never completes loading.

[image: Google Analytics takers forever to load]

This keeps on going forever. The code is the standard code as recommended by Google:

```html
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I think it's some kind of clever way by Google to measure page view time. They maybe just only return the headers and wait with a body response. They wait for a user to click away probably causing the browser to give up and close the connection.

I don't know if this is true, but it's a guess. Anybody seen this behaviour as well and know the reason behind it?

Comment: Not loading its own tracking library would not be very clever for a tracking tool. Plus I'm not seeing anything like this, are you sure that isn't just a local thing within your network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requests were blocked by uBlock Origin. Temporarily disabling that browser extension fixed it.

Comment: Could you accept your own answer (will not give you any rep but the question won't show up in the unanswered tab). Thanks.

Comment: I will but SO doesn't allow me, I have two wait 2 days.